# Creating custom icon which listens to changes in API and changes it's color according to it on Android

Tags: android, api, event-listener, uielement

I am trying to implement a custom icon which changes its color based on API response (Green stands for idle and red one stands for busy). What I have done so far I got a response from API about printer-state if it is idle or not and created a new method which checks if the printer is idle or not, if yes returns true, it not returns false. My problem is I am not which event handler I should use for the custom icon to implement this isIdle() method or if there is any other approach for this situation?

I have custom adapter class where I display printer name, it's model and I need to display the states of it, all this information comes from API.

Here is the image of how it should look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6h2k.jpg

Here is my adapter class in case it helps.

```
public class NsdServiceInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PrinterNew> {
private Context mContext;
private List<PrinterNew> services;
private InetAddress hostAddress;


layout id (list item layout Id) and data model.

public NsdServiceInfoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int layoutId, 
List<PrinterNew> list) {
    super(context, layoutId, list);
    mContext = context;
    services = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override


public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;


    if (listItem == null)
        listItem = 
LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    PrinterNew currentService = services.get(position);



    TextView t = listItem.findViewById(R.id.TextView_serviceName);
    TextView r = listItem.findViewById(R.id.TextView_serviceIP);
    r.setText("model: " + currentService.getPrinterModel());
    t.setText("name: " + currentService.getPrinterName());


    Log.d("TAG", "model" + String.valueOf(currentService.getPrinterModel()));
    Log.d("hello2", String.valueOf(currentService.getPrinterName()));


    return listItem;
}

}
```

Here is my isIdle() method in Printer class

```
    public boolean isIdle() {
    if (state == -1 && currentMenu == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have boolean value for the state. Just Take ImageView for setting a circular icon and apply a color filter based on boolean Like: 
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY);

Comment: ok, I will try to do that, so I suppose I create new method where I check if boolean is true and false and  based on that I assign color filter . What about adapter do I need to call this new method in the adapter class ?